# Pushing Through OK On SVN Update Via Command Line?

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I'm using the following line to update a directory via the Windows/DOS command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"C:\MyPath\"
```

After that line, I have it build the solution.  It's working great, except for one thing.  When it finishes updating, you have to press "OK" on the SVN Update window when it completes to go to the next step.

Is there any way to automatically bypass this, or better yet, have this run without the SVN Update window ever showing up?

I'd really appreciate help in this matter, thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind installing another program, get the [command-line svn client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/) and just do `svn up c:\MyPath`

Comment: Hey, I decided the SVN window was just too much and decided to go with your suggestion.  It's working like a champ now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `/closeonend` flag.

[This link](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) has useful command line info.

Comment: /closeonend:1 is what I used specifically to solve this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use a command line svn client, like [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

Comment: +1 for the 'obvious' answer.  However I still like the GUI version for some things (diffing, for example)

Comment: Yes, but they are compatible, I use TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN for all manual operations and the command line client for automating stuff. They work seamlessly on the same working copy.

Comment: I find TortoiseSVN command line arguments cumbersome and non standard, I prefer the regular command line client when doing command line operations.